# How to remove Cloudfront Headers on Viewer Response (Set-Cookie)

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I would like to remove the "ASP.NET_SessionId" Set-Cookie header from the Cloudfront response.

```
set-cookie: lang=en;
set-cookie: lang-favorite=en;path=/
set-cookie: gxplang=E;
set-cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=sdfdsf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Lambda @Edge Function to the Viewer Response Behaviour of Cloudfront:

```
'use strict';

const discardHeader = 'ASP.NET_SessionId=';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const setCookieHeaders = response.headers['set-cookie'];

    if(setCookieHeaders && setCookieHeaders.length > 0)
    {
        response.headers['set-cookie'] = setCookieHeaders.filter( h => h.value.indexOf(discardHeader) < 0 );
    }      
    return callback(null, response);    
};
```